# Why does the following code not set the pathname as expected, when using URL.pathname?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to fix, and stumbled on this. Why does the following not output `localhost:3000/something`?

```js
const url = new URL('localhost:3000');
url.pathname = '/something';

console.log(url.toString())
```

I did some experiments, and found out including `http://` will "fix" it, but why is like this?

Comment: `localhost:3000` isn't a valid URL to begin with, because the protocol is missing - as you already discovered. It would instead be interpreted as a URI with a scheme of `localhost` and a scheme-specific part of `3000` which is neither logical nor what you want nor supported by `new URL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that `URL` detects `localhost:` as a URI scheme, or as the Web APIs call it, [`protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/protocol).

```js
const url = new URL('localhost:3000');
console.log(url.protocol);
```

As far as I know there is no way to achieve this without putting a *valid URI scheme* in your URL object. You can get current protocol with `location.protocol` and set it to explicitly define some protocol.

```js
const url = new URL(`${location.protocol}localhost:3000`);
url.pathname = '/something';
console.log(url.toString())
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'm in Sveltekit, server side rendering, and no access to `location`, so will have to be creative but really good to understand why :)

Comment: @dauldk Good point. My solution works **only in browser**. You have to find your protocol somewhere else :).